# Using Boost Karma to replace std::stringstream for double to std::string Conversion

Tags: c++, performance, std, boost-spirit

For performance improvement, I am looking to replace:

```
template<class T> std::string ToStringFixed(const T x, const unsigned int width = 8)
{
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << std::setprecision(width) << std::fixed << x;
  return ss.str();
}
```

With an implementation from Boost Karma as our project already uses Boost and it looks to have a significant performance gain over the naive solution above.

Something like:

```
std::string ToString(double d)
{
  using boost::spirit::karma::double_;
  using boost::spirit::ascii::space;
  using boost::spirit::karma::generate;

  std::string s
  std::back_insert_iterator<std::string> sink(s);
  generate(sink, double_, d);
  return s;
}
```

Which is adopted from: http://thisthread.blogspot.com/2011/04/generating-text-with-spirit-karma.html seems to be on the right track, but it isn't clear to me how to control the precision, or if such a solution can be template-friendly for floating point types without use of type traits.  (Answers using up through C++14 are acceptable.)

Comment: @NeilButterworth To the best of my knowledge, std::to_string does not allow for controlling the format.  Here I am wanting to control the precision. Other functions may also want to control the width of the output.  All of this is easy with std::stringstream, but I would like a more performance-oriented solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with the help of [`real_generator`'s formatting policies](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/karma/reference/numeric/real_number.html#spirit.karma.reference.numeric.real_number.real_number_formatting_policies). Since you only need to modify the precision you can derive from the default `real_policies<Num>` and then add the `precision(Num n)` member function that has the behaviour you need.

[Running on WandBox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ZfAwTb0hjHU0Pc5l)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>

template <typename Num>
struct precision_policy : boost::spirit::karma::real_policies<Num>
{
    precision_policy(int prec):precision_(prec){}
    int precision(Num n) const { return precision_; }
    int precision_;
};

std::string ToStringFixedKarma(double d, const unsigned int width = 8)
{
  using boost::spirit::karma::real_generator;
  using boost::spirit::ascii::space;
  using boost::spirit::karma::generate;

  real_generator<double,precision_policy<double> > my_double_(width);

  std::string s;
  std::back_insert_iterator<std::string> sink(s);
  generate(sink, my_double_, d);
  return s;
}

int main() {
    const double pi = std::acos(-1);
    std::cout << ToStringFixedKarma(pi) << std::endl;
    std::cout << ToStringFixedKarma(pi,2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << ToStringFixedKarma(pi,4) << std::endl;
}
```

PS: The documentation (and inspecting the source) seems to imply that the member functions in these policies need to be static, which would make what you need impossible, but as [this example](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/example/karma/printf_style_double_format.cpp) shows, that is not the case.