# Match round behavior of std::stringstream with boost::spirit::karma::real_generator

Tags: c++, boost

I want to match the output of `boost::spirit::karma::real_generator` to the output of `std::stringstream`.

The following code converts the double `8612.0078125` to `std::string` with precision 6 using:

1. `stringstream` and `std::setprecision`
2. `boost::spirit::karma::real_generator`

However, they behave differently in the last digit.
The output:

```
8612.007812
8612.007813
```

I checked [`karma::real_policies`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/boost/spirit/home/karma/numeric/real_policies.hpp) if there was a policy for rounding behavior, but `n` is already 7813 when `fraction_part` is called.

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>

#include <iomanip>

template <typename T>
struct precision_policy : boost::spirit::karma::real_policies<T>
{
  int floatfield(T n) const { return boost::spirit::karma::real_policies<T>::fmtflags::fixed; } // Always Fixed
  bool trailing_zeros(T n) const{ return true; }

  precision_policy(int prec):precision_(prec){}
  int precision(T n) const { return precision_; }
  int precision_;
  
};
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42255919/using-boost-karma-to-replace-stdstringstream-for-double-to-stdstring-convers
std::string ToStringFixedKarma(double d, const unsigned int width = 6)
{
  using boost::spirit::karma::real_generator;
  using boost::spirit::ascii::space;
  using boost::spirit::karma::generate;

  real_generator<double,precision_policy<double> > my_double_(width);

  std::string s;
  std::back_insert_iterator<std::string> sink(s);
  generate(sink, my_double_, d);
  return s;
}

int main(){

  double my_double = 8612.0078125;

  std::stringstream description;
  description << std::fixed << std::setprecision(6)
              << my_double << "\n";
              
  std::cout << description.str();
  
  std::cout << ToStringFixedKarma(my_double) << "\n";

}
```

Comment: I feel like boost has gone off the rails with their naming.

Comment: @sweenish I'd like to know what the guy was smoking that came up with `...karma::real...`

Comment: Such informative discourse in the comments. [Is hackernews down?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate to be that guy, but this strongly feels like a problem of square pegs and round holes.

Karma has its use, but in isolation to format reals, I would not consider it inevitable.

The linked answer suggests that you might be after the performance boost. I suspect that this can also be had by using a stream on the same `std::string` instance repeatedly. Here is a simple take that - obviously - replicates the `iostream` behaviour:

```
std::string ToStringFixedNoKarma(double d, const unsigned int width = 6) {
    using D = boost::iostreams::back_insert_device<std::string>;
    std::string s;
    boost::iostreams::stream<D> ss(D{s});
    ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(width) << d;
    return s;
}
```

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8901ea8f72bc838)**

You can expect it to be faster due to the ability to move from the string result and/or to reuse the backing string instance.

---

Other ideas/source of inspiration:

- Boost Convert has an array of conversion methods, including [benchmarks](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/convert/doc/html/boost_convert/performance.html#boost_convert.performance.converters_compared)

  [image]

  Also note the remark about Karma performance.
- If you're after correctness and speed, consider [Libfmt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt):

  > - Fast IEEE 754 floating-point formatter with correct rounding,
  >   shortness and round-trip guarantees

  They too publish benchmarks:

  [image]
- C++17 has the new [`to_chars` in `<charconv>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_chars). Sadly GCC [doesn't implement it fully](http://gcc.1065356.n8.nabble.com/What-s-the-status-of-to-chars-from-chars-for-floating-point-types-td1602602.html) yet (but MSVC does).

In an attempt to be helpful a bit here's a side-by-side of many of the approaches mentioned:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/PaafsG)**

```
#include <boost/convert.hpp>
#include <boost/convert/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/convert/parameters.hpp>
#include <boost/convert/printf.hpp>
#include <boost/convert/stream.hpp>
#include <boost/convert/strtol.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/back_inserter.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>
#include <fmt/printf.h>
#include <charconv>

#include <iostream>
using Reference = boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_100;

std::string ToStringFixedKarma(double d, const unsigned int width = 6) {
    using D = boost::iostreams::back_insert_device<std::string>;
    std::string s;
    boost::iostreams::stream<D> ss(D{s});
    ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(width) << d;
    return s;
}

void comparisons(std::string_view label, Reference value, auto converter) {
    double d = value.convert_to<double>();
    float  f = value.convert_to<float>();

    std::cout << " ---- " << label << "\n";
    std::cout << "float"  << converter(f) << "\n";
    std::cout << "double" << converter(d) << "\n";
}

int main() {
    namespace cnv = boost::cnv;
    namespace arg = boost::cnv::parameter;
    cnv::cstream      _cs;
    cnv::lexical_cast _lc; // not able to control format
    cnv::strtol       _stl;
    cnv::printf       _pf;

    Reference const reference("8612.0078125");
    std::cout << "Reference: " << reference.str(20, std::ios::fixed) << "\n";

    _cs(std::fixed)(std::setprecision(6));
    _stl(arg::notation = cnv::notation::fixed)(arg::precision = 6);
    _pf(arg::notation = cnv::notation::fixed)(arg::precision = 6);

    auto cs  = cnv::apply<std::string>(boost::cref(_cs));
    auto stl = cnv::apply<std::string>(boost::cref(_stl));
    auto pf  = cnv::apply<std::string>(boost::cref(_pf));
    auto lc  = cnv::apply<std::string>(boost::cref(_lc));

    comparisons("cstream", reference, cs);
    comparisons("strtol", reference, stl);
    comparisons("printf", reference, pf);
    comparisons("libfmt", reference, [](auto v) { return fmt::format(FMT_STRING("{:.10}"), v); });
#ifdef __cpp_lib_to_chars
    comparisons("charconv", reference,
                [buf = std::array<char, 30>{}](auto v) mutable {
                    auto r = std::to_chars(buf.data(), buf.data() + buf.size(),
                                        v, std::chars_format::fixed, 6);
                    return std::string_view(buf.data(), r.ptr - buf.begin());
                });
#endif
    comparisons("lexical_cast", reference, lc);
}
```

Prints

```
Reference: 8612.00781250000000000000
 ---- cstream
float8612.007812
double8612.007812
 ---- strtol
float8612.007813
double8612.007813
 ---- printf
float8612.007812
double8612.007812
 ---- libfmt
float8612.007812
double8612.007812
 ---- lexical_cast
float8612.00781
double8612.0078125
```